# BEGINNER Angular4 Component Trouble Shoot

Tags: javascript, angular, oop, typescript

**** UPDATED CODE ***** 
hey everyone new to angular 4 and im trying to make a simple component that displays the month and date which is getting its data from this [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

here is my `data.model.ts` file

```
export class Dater {

    date = new Date();
    month: number = this.date.getMonth(); 
    day: number = this.date.getDate();

    constructor() {
    }

}
```

which im getting the following error
`Cannot find name 'date' Did you mean instance member 'this.date'?`

and then my `date.component.ts` file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Dater } from './dater.model'; // here i reference my date class
@Component({
  selector: 'app-date',
  templateUrl: './date.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date.component.css']
})
export class DateComponent implements OnInit {

  date: Dater; // assign property to type Date class
  constructor() { 
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and my view file `date.component.html`

```
<p>
  date works!
  {{date.month}}
</p>
```

i would like to also add that my understanding of OOP is not that great, YET :) thanks for all the help!

after updating my code i now get the following error
`Cannot read property 'month' of undefined`

Comment: its as the error says use `this.date.getMonth()`

Comment: @suraj now im getting the following error `Property 'getMonth' does not exist on type Date`

Comment: I dont see getMonth function..I think you have a name clash..you are creating a class with the same `Date` name

Comment: @suraj im trying to get that function from the native javascript date object

Comment: yes. but your custom model class has the same name..

Comment: @helloworld I think `suraj` is right, you should change class name Date , it language type name and we should avoid to naming with it.

Comment: @ThienHoang I've updated my code to reflect what @suraji has said and now im getting the following error `Cannot read property 'month' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside scope of component, we have use `this` to ref to properties or function, that is class context.

```
export class Dater {

   date: Date = new Date();
   month: number = this.date.getMonth(); 
   day: number = this.date.getDate();

   constructor() {

   }

}`
```

In template, The expression context is typically the component instance (object context), in this case is DateComponent object context.

We missed declare instance so it will be undefined.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Dater } from './dater.model'; // here i reference my date class
@Component({
  selector: 'app-date',
  templateUrl: './date.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date.component.css']
})
export class DateComponent implements OnInit {

  date: Dater = new Dater();
  constructor() { 
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

You can ref to this Angular 2 docs for more understanding about Angular 2 context https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html

Comment: thanks! everything worked. but importing the class doesnt give us access to its property??? seems weird to declare the instance. what am i miss understanding

Comment: This is OOP , we just can access property of class when declare instace (object). Unless we set it static type.

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes, you should not have a **`keyword`** as a class name, and when you assign use **`this`** with typescript,

the following should work,

```
export class myClass {
    date = new Date();
    month: number = this.date.getMonth();
    day: number = this.date.getDate();
    constructor() {
    }

}
```

Comment: im getting the following error `Cannot read property 'month' of undefined` ive changed my class name to `Dater` for the sake of getting things to work. my view still isnt rendering

Comment: update your template like this <p>
  date works!
  {{date?.month}}
</p>

Comment: updated. but nothing is being rendered, also no console errors.

Comment: debug and see if month is getting assigned

Comment: how would i do that? where would i put my console.log statement?

Answer (score 0):

This is purely a Typescript class Instantiation Problem where the Dater class in the model is not instantiated in the DateComponent.ts 
You can learn more about Typescript Classes  in  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

```
date = new Dater();
```

This will do the trick